# How easy is it to develop hardware to run Microsoft Robotics?

Tags: microsoft, robotics, embedded, software

What do I need to develop hardware that can run embedded software developed with the [Microsoft Robotics](http://www.microsoft.com/switzerland/education/en/academiczone/students/robotics.mspx) studio? I thought only certain high-end off-the-shelf robots that support embedded Linux were capable of running such software.

Do you have any experience with MS Robotics? and is it possible for me to develop my own custom-built hardware in-house so I don't have to buy some expensive robot simply to play with the MS Robotics studio and the Visual Programming Language (VPL) that is included within the package?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specifically answerable and has been abandoned for *years*.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb483043.aspx) site in Tutorial #6 , it seems that you can create control applications if your robot doesn't run the .NET framework (likely if you decide to roll your own).  From the tutorial, it looks like it would be possible to write an interface to control pretty much anything you can come up with, though I admit I didn't give it an exhaustive consideration.

That being said, it does seem to support a wide array of robots according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Robotics_Developer_Studio#Supported_robots) and several of those models aren't exactly "high-end".  You may find something up your alley, and it would undoubtedly be easier to start out with, say, a [Parallax BOE-Bot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boe-Bot) than building something from scratch and creating all the interfaces.

There is, apparently, a simulated robot environment as well.  According to the Wikipedia article linked above, you can, "simulate the behavior  of robots in a virtual world using NVIDIA PhysX technology (3D engine originally written by Ageia) that includes advanced physics."  Microsoft makes extensive reference to the Ageia physics engine on their site as well.  If you have an idea you want to try out, this might be a free way of doing so.  I haven't really looked at this environment, though, so anything other than what I quoted from the sources is speculation here.

I have not used the MS Robotics environment at all, so all of this comes from the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Ther must be better way, but since roomba protocol specification is open and it uses serial interface it should be not very hard to implement roombas api in your robot and lay to MSRS (that has support for Roomba) that it is true Roomba.

useful links:

- http://www.irobot.com/images/consumer/hacker/Roomba_SCI_Spec_Manual.pdf protocol specification
- http://hackingroomba.com/code/roombacomm/ open source Roomba client implementation